# How to add classpath in an Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, classpath

I have an Android project with an Android application that depends on a pure Java library (and the Java library uses some others compiled jars libraries).
 I added the dependencies, I can build the project, but at run time I have a `ClassNotFoundException` error.
I had to add  to the`CLASSPATH`environment variable the path to the jars.
Is there a way to set the classpath locally for the project only, like using the command line option

```
java –classpath <path to the jars>
```

in the Android studio Run/Debug Configurations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to the Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Answer (score 18):

First off all, be sure there's a "libs" subfolder in the "app" folder of your project. If there's not, create one.
Next, in the app/build.gradle file, add this line of code:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile fileTree(dir:'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

Place all of your .jar files in the "libs" folder, and voila, you're done

Comment: and locate the .jar file from step 1) this line are not clear.. where .jar file in my project.

Comment: This does not work for me. Whenever I try this and build, I get errors saying that there is no resource file matching any color( for example colorAccent or colorPrimary) and it can't find any parent for item Theme.appCompat etc.

Comment: Concerning #8 "if module is listed"...what If I followed all the preceding steps and it is not?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Arnold Layne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31372941/1320237), I created a folder named libs.

Then, I went to

Files -> Project Structure (new menu opens) -> Modules (on the left) -> app -> Dependencies

There, I could add the library with the `+` Button.

This created this entry:

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/commons-lang3-3.7.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to `build.gradle` of `app` module.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation files('libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16')
    ...
}
```