# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: for using JavaML libsvm in Android

Tags: java, android, libsvm

I am using java ml for lib svm. But I am getting                                                                   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: libsvm.LibSVM$1 error while initializing a LibSvm object. I have added these lines in my gradle:

```html
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile project(':javaml-0.1.7')
}
```

This is the Activity code. The error occurs when I initialize libSVM.

```html
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import net.sf.javaml.core.Dataset;

import libsvm.LibSVM;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public LibSVM libSVM;
    Dataset dataset;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            libSVM = new LibSVM();

    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using proguard, make sure you added required rules

Comment: I am using JavaML Libsvm for android

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549159/add-javaml-library-to-android-project, i personally never used Libsvm.. you might have to fix proguard for release build-type (Not needed for debug build-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only added the javaml-0.1.7.jar before.
But there is also a libsvm.jar in the lib folder of javaml-0.1.7.
Importing that library solved the problem.